# Plotting circle

Tags: r

I want to draw a circle like [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/function-grapher.php?func1=2%20sqrt(25-(x-4)%5E2)&func2=2-sqrt(25-(x-4)%5E2)&xmin=-12&xmax=12&ymin=-8&ymax=8).

The equation of the circle is : (x-4)^2+(y-2)^2=25

So i wrote down R codes using `curve` command. But it  is not drawing circle exactly.

```
 curve(4-sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),xlim=c(-4,10),ylim=c(-4,10))

 curve(4+sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),add=TRUE,col="red")
```

and it is producing circle like following :[image].

Where is/are the fault(s) in my commands? also the commands produce warning

```
 Warning message:
 In sqrt(25 - (x - 2)^2) : NaNs produced
```

I know there is a function `draw.circle` in R.

But i want to identify my codes fault(s).

Comment: there are far better, and simpler, ways to draw a circle centered at a specified origin and known radius.  Look around a bit.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: OP implies that they are doing this for pedagogical reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning message comes from the fact that you try to take `sqrt()` of a negative number. The circle can be drawn by increasing the data-points.:

```
N<-10000
curve(4-sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),xlim=c(-4,10),ylim=c(-4,10),n=N)
curve(4+sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),add=TRUE,col="red",n=N)
```

of course you should in general use the arguments of `from`,`to` to control the calculations of the data-points pointed out by Ben:

```
curve(4-sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),xlim=c(-4,10),ylim=c(-4,10),from=-3,to=7,n=N)
curve(4+sqrt(25-(x-2)^2),add=TRUE,col="red",from=-3,to=7,n=N)
```

also notice you are plotting (y,x) and not the usual (x,y). Judging by the comments, it seems you want:

```
curve(2-sqrt(25-(x-4)^2),xlim=c(-4,10),ylim=c(-4,10),from=-1,to=9,n=N)
curve(2+sqrt(25-(x-4)^2),add=TRUE,col="red",from=-1,to=9,n=N)
```

Comment: It is also producing warning and  i didn't understood the reason why didn't `xlim` and `ylim`  cover it ? Why did i need to add `n` and if i would use `from= , to= ` argument inside curve instead of `xlim` and `ylim` , could i able to draw the circle parfectly ?

Comment: `xlim` and `ylim` are arguments to `plot`, `from` and `to` is used by `curve` to calculate the datapoints, eg. ensure you are not trying to take `sqrt()` of a negative number in this case. I just increased the number of points because it was a quick fix.

Comment: But (4,7) should be a point on circumference. But it is not so. I've justified it by `abline(h=7,v=4)`

Comment: That's simply because you switched x,y in your own code of the plot. Try `abline(h=4,v=7)` or `curve(2-sqrt(25-(x-4)^2),xlim=c(-4,10),ylim=c(-4,10),n=N); curve(2+sqrt(25-(x-4)^2),add=TRUE,col="red",n=N)`

Comment: I might just delete my answer since your answer covers it.  I think that once you specify `from` and `to`, however, you really don't need to increase `N` -- the default 101 points should be just fine. 10000 is overkill.

Comment: Though i have read the help line `?curve` not understood the thing that what purpose did you keep in mind to use the both arguments `from=,to=` and `xlim=,ylim= `,also the `n` argument that you have used inside the curve function ?

Comment: When `xlim=` is not specified,what does it imply?Does it take value `c(from=,to=)` by default?

Comment: yes `xlim=` will then narrow it down to almost `c(from=,to=)` and `ylim=` given by `c( min(f(x)), max(f(x)) )` where `f()` is the function given as argument to curve.